# Trip optimization (maximize your layover)

Tags: java

You have `a[X]` hour layover in Paris and want to book some trips. You prefer to book as few trips as possible to enjoy the last `[X]` hours with minimum context switch.

How there is no time cost for transportation between trips.

Input 
An array of trips duration (hours)

```
e.g.[1,3,6]
```

Total remaining hours `e.g.15`

Minimum number of purchases `e.g. 3(6+6+3=15)`

If there is no way to fill total remaining hours,`return-1.`

**Input sample:**

```
136
15
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Please help me in `java` or any language.

Comment: Some quotes from the Web page [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) (1) It is okay to ask about homework. (2) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. (3) Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be solved using [Knapsack problem](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-knapsack-problem) or [Minimum Coin Change problem](https://afteracademy.com/blog/minimum-coin-change), both are optimization problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
func minCoin(trips: [Int], total_hours:Int) -> Int {
    if(total_hours == 0) {
        return 0
    }
    let m: Int = trips.count
    var min: Int = Int(INT_MAX)
    for i in 0..<m {
        if(trips[i] <= total_hours)
        {
            let curr_min: Int = minCoin(trips:trips, total_hours:(total_hours-trips[i]))
            if(curr_min != INT_MAX && curr_min + 1 < min){
               min = curr_min + 1
            }
        }
    }
    return min
}
```

**Java**

```
int minCoin(int trips[], int total_hours)
{
   if(total_hours == 0)
     return 0
   int m = trips.length;
   int min = INT_MAX 
   for(int i = 0; i++; i<m)
   {
      if(trips[i] <= total_hours)
      {
         int curr_min = minCoin(trips, total_hours-trips[i])
         if(curr_min != INT_MAX && curr_min + 1 < min)
           min = curr_min + 1
      }
   }
   return min
}
```